# socket send and EWOULDBLOCK

Tags: c, sockets, send

In socket communication:

1. In blocking mode, `send()` will return the number of byte sent, then I have to repeat `send()` until all data has been sent or socket error.
2. In non-blocking mode, `send()` will return with EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK error if it cannot send all data immediately, then, I will `select()` on writefds param until I have the signal.

My questions:

1. Is the signal from `select()` for all data? (not partial).
2. Is the error from `select()` as socket failure?

Answer (score 1):

> In non-blocking mode, `send()` will return with EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK error if it cannot send all data immediately

If it cannot send *any* data immediately.

> 1. Is the signal from select() for all data? (not partial).

All what data? What does `select()` know about your data? All that it is telling you is that the socket has now become writable, which means there is some space in the kernel socket send buffer, which means that a `send()` will now transfer at least one byte.

> 2. Is the error from select() as socket failure?

If `select()` returns -1, there is either an error in the parameters or an invalid FD supplied to one of the select sets: typically, one that has been closed.

Comment: (1) i already asked send() to send that much of data. select() will inform if an "fd" has something to report.

Comment: And it didn't. So? `select()` doesn't know that. System calls don't know about each other's prior failures, or the parameters that were supplied to those failures.

Comment: so, how di i know if all data has been sent?

Comment: You knew because you got EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK from `send()`, or else a count of bytes transferred.

Comment: I will consider adjusting this answer when and if you state clearly what it is that you think needs adjusting. I can't see any need for it myself. It answers the questions you asked. The commentary here is essentially redundant.